# Add new Array of numbers to Gridview after using OnclickItemListener

Tags: android, gridview, arraylist, onitemclicklistener

I'm trying to reload a `GridView` by clicking a button to generate and fill new array of numbers to my `GridView`. Here is my code without read new Array:

```
gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
final ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,randomArray(arrayNumbers));

gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            gridView=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView);
            Integer values=Integer.parseInt(gridView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
            y.setText(String.valueOf(value));

            if (a==values) {
                Collections.shuffle(randomArray(arrayNumbers));//xao tron vi tri cua cac so trong gridview
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//reload lai gridview
                a = a + r.nextInt(11);//tang gia tri a
                x.setText(String.valueOf(a));
                System.out.println(a);
                //Todo set gia tri a vao mang random(1) vua tao moi
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

       }
})
```

and here is my Randomnumber method:

```
public static ArrayList randomArray(int[] a){
    Random r= new Random();
    List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<>();
    for (int j=1;j<25;){
        int random=((int)(Math.random()*100))+1;
        if (!list.contains(random)){
            list.add (random);
            j++;
        }
    }
    list.add(30);

    return (ArrayList) list;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hold a reference to the list:

```
numbersArrayList = randomArray(arrayNumbers);
final ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbersArrayList);
```

And then without changing the reference you can update the items in your `OnItemClickListener`:

```
numbersArrayList.clear();
List<Integer> newList = randomArray(arrayNumbers);
Collections.shuffle(newList);
numbersArrayList.addAll(newList);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: sorry but my Collection is not applied for Void method, what shoul'd i have to do?

Comment: I'm just show my AlertDialog, but any field outside it has been disabled, how can i enable/show a RestartGame button from the outside while showing DialogBox?

Comment: I can't see your AlertDialog in the code that you posted, but you can post a new question and I will be glad to help you. If this solution works for you please mark the answer as accepted, thanks!

Comment: thank you. This is the link of my question
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38268298/how-to-enable-button-when-alertdialog-has-activated/38268520?noredirect=1#comment63957021_38268520]